# Numpy Array minimum computation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

I'm supposed to create a function that executes the following: I have two datasets U and X filled with vectors. For the dataset X I also have a Labelset Y containing 0 and 1. Now I should calculate for every vector in U the closest one in X and and only output the label to the corresponding vector of X. For example, if U[0] is closest to X[5], and Y[5] = 1, I should get 1 as a result. Let's take an exapmle:

```
import numpy as np
X1 = np.array([[2.5, 2.8, 2.8], [2.6, 2.7, 2.9], [2.6, 2.7, 3.0]])
U1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 7, 8]])
Y1 = np.array([1, 1, 0])
```

Calculating the distances and get the closest one is easy. I use scipy.spatial.distance.cdist() and np.min()

```
import scipy
from scipy.spatial import distance

def npbatch(U: Dataset, X: Dataset, Y: LabelList) -> np.ndarray:
    W = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(U,X)
    Z = np.min(W, axis = 1)
    return Z
```

Now the function gives me back an Array with the closest distances between each vector in U and X. But I didn't use the labels in Y yet.
I know I should use the zip() function as well as a key for this task. But I just can't figure out how to do it. Can somebody please give me an hint or something? Also I'm not supposed to use any loops.

Answer (score 0):

`np.argmin()` will give you the indices of the minimum values in an array, such that `arr[np.argmin(arr, axis=1)]` is the same as `np.min(arr, axis=1)`.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped a lot, I was able to solve it :)